# Can one use realm.io in Windows Forms App or WPF apps?

Tags: realm

Realm.io now supports Xamarin. Does it mean I could even use it for Windows Forms and WPF apps written in C#?

If yes, then where will the apps's realm file located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now Realm Xamarin works only on Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android according to [the system requirements](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#prerequisites). There is an [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/526) open about WPF support on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Now realm supports .net core using which you can develop for server side and desktop application. 
Details can be found in the below link 
https://realm.io/blog/introducing-dot-net-core-support-for-realm/